# Android Development Outside Eclipse

Tags: android

I'm very much a creature of habit, and feel most at home editing in vim, jumping back and forth in screen.  That said, I'm really enjoying Android development, with Eclipse being the only major point that I find a PITA (no offense to Eclipse fans, I'm sure it's a great tool, it's just not the bee's knees for me).

Can anyone point me to a tutorial or resource on getting set up to do Android development entirely outside the Eclipse tool chain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/hello-world.html (at the bottom)

which links to:

http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/other-ide.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use [IntelliJ IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) and its Android support plugin. Please see more detailed info [here](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?idea&id=1792).

PS: Link to a step-by-step tutorial for an environment set up:

http://code.google.com/p/idea-android/wiki/GettingStarted